# can't seem to locate the struct

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to fetch values from a struct once its been updated however the problem am facing is an undeclared error as it cannot seem to see it.

sonicNav.h file

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"sonicThread.h"

extern void calcSonicS();
```

sonicThread.c file.

```
    int funcLock = 0;

    void calcSonicS() {
       struct results *rData = results;
       rData = malloc(sizeof(struct results));

       int newVal1 = rData->sens1;
       int newVal2 = rData->sens2;
       int newVal3 = rData->sens3;
       int newVal4 = rData->sens4;

       if(funcLock == 0){
       funcLock = threadFunc();//returns INT value of 1.

     }
      printf("value 1: %d value 2: %d value 3: %d value 4 %d\n", newVal1, newVal2, newVal3, newVal4);
}
```

sonicThread.h file

```
#pragma once
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<wiringPi.h>


//GPIO PINS stored within structs, for each sonic range finder.
typedef struct sonicPins{
//pins and id.
int trig;
int echo;
int id;
}args;

typedef struct results{
//all pins
int sens1;
int sens2;
int sens3;
int sens4;

}rData;
```

sonicThread.c file

```
void* setup(void  *pinsPtr);
extern int threadFunc();

pthread_t pt[4];

int threadFunc()
{
  struct  sonicPins pinsArray[4] = { { 21, 20, 1 }, { 16, 12, 2 }, { 26, 19, 3 }, { 13, 6, 4 } };
  for(int i =0; i <4; i++){
  pthread_create(&pt[i], NULL, setup, &pinsArray[i] );
   }
return 1;
}

void* setup(void *pinsPtr)
{
   struct sonicPins *ptr = pinsPtr;
   int trig = 0, Echo = 0, id;
   trig = ptr->trig;
   Echo = ptr->echo;
   id = ptr->id;
   struct  results *storePtr;
}
```

The snippet above does update the struct "results", all threads does work concurrently each sensor giving out is own result.

Main.c

```
int main(){
//void(*foo1)(int, int, int);
//foo1 = &calcSonicS;

printf("In operation\n");
int operational = 1;

while(operational ==1)
{
//sonic range finders.
  calcSonicS();
//gyroscope and acceometer.
}
return 0;
}
```

Error output:

```
sonicNav.c: In function ‘calcSonicS’:
sonicNav.c:5:28: error: ‘results’ undeclared (first use in this function)
sonicNav.c:5:28: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Comment: Put spaces after `#include`s

Comment: Thanks for that I didn't notice at first there was spaces there but not enough I guess

Comment: What you mean where i saw it last?

Comment: "I can't find my thingummy" - "Where did you see it last?"

Comment: If your just going to troll I suggest you delete your post and stop trolling. Its obvious what this thread is referring too

Comment: What do you expect this line to do `struct results *rData = results;`, specifically the right side ?

Comment: It would add *significant* help to your question if instead of simply labelling posted snippets as "h file" and "c file", you actually provided *the files names* as well.

Comment: EXCUSE ME I am pretty new to C and so I should not know everything about the language.  struct results *rData = results; what i expect this to do? Well first time I ever posted something like this I was advised to it that way and it worked. True but the includes kinds of gives that away tbf

Comment: It's a very nice response to an exact pointer to your problem. If you don't have an idea what you are doing, probably the specific answers won't help you as well. Good luck with that.

Comment: It is supposed to do something with a variable of type `struct results` which is called `results`. It is nowhere to be seen in what you have posted, as informed by the compiler.

Comment: @JamesSmith Eugene's question is entirely valid. That line of code didn't manufacture itself. You had intent in writing it. What was that intent? it may-well be helpful in explaining what the *correct* thing to write would be. `struct results *rData = results;` looks terribly odd. `rData` is an alias for the  `struct results` *type*, declared in a header, and the right-side of that initialization is something called `results` that has no apparent definition whatsoever. I think simply `struct results *rData;` will work for you, but I strongly advise a different variable name.

Comment: I don't know to whom you're referencing, but I've been more than cordial in my comments. Daniel has provided a nice answer that is sincerely worthy of review, and addresses what I mentioned. I suggest it be looked over, and if it helps, appropriately upticked or selected for outright-solution.

Comment: @WhozCraig It was toward my direction, I guess. He doesn't even realize I've gave him the answer.

Comment: Question maybe valid but his level of tone isn't. I am not new to programming int itself in fact I started coding back in 1994. I am simply not used to C as of yet. And my side of the globe that level of tone is considered to be rude and is unjustified on this thread.

Comment: @JamesSmith: You might be living on the third side of the globe (how many sides does a globe have?). I don't see anything offending in one of the comments. If you do not get the point, you should just ask, but not just complain without getting to the point. As a long-term programmer you should  very well be able to interpret the message yourself - unless you are only familar with a **very** esotheric language.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct results *rData = results;
```

> error: ‘results’ undeclared (first use in this function)

The above line tries to declare and define a local variable named `rData`, which has type `struct results *`, and initialise it with the value of the variable (local or global) `results`. The error message is telling you that there is no such variable.

What you're probably mixing up is C++ (old, bad) style initialisation:

```
MyClass variable = MyClass();
```

Since the next thing you do with `rData` is assigning it ...

```
rData = malloc(sizeof(struct results));
```

... the solution to your issue is to just remove that "wrong initialisation" from the preceeding line altogether. You could also pack it into a single line:

```
struct results *rData = malloc(sizeof(struct results));
```

---

Looking at ...

```
typedef struct results{
  // ...
} rData;
```

... I'd guess that you have a serious misunderstanding of the relationship of structure (type) names, type names and variable names. The above definition gives you:

- The name `results` as structure (type) name, so it can be used after `struct` to name the defined structure type.
- The name `rData` as type name, referring to the same (structure) type as `struct results`.

When you then declare a variable `struct results *rData` you have *additionally* `rData` as name for a variable. This is possible, but far from good style.

If you remove the `typedef`, then things would change drastically: You'd then have a global variable named `rData` of type `struct results`.

Comment: Sure am so used to OOP. I did try as you suggested but it throws out the same error. That was 1 of the first methods I tried, did try again just now and still no luck.

Comment: I can hardly believe that you get "the same error", what's the exact error?

Comment: sonicNav.c: In function ‘calcSonicS’:
sonicNav.c:5:46: error: ‘results’ undeclared (first use in this function)
sonicNav.c:5:46: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in . PS I changed to struct results *resultPtr  = malloc(sizeof(results)); as its not correct as its same as the alias but again it has nothing to do with the error being thrown.

Comment: What exact text is at `5:46` ?

Comment: AH, ok, `sizeof(results)` tries to get the size of (the type of) the (local, global) variable named `results`. You need to write `struct results` here.

Comment: ... or `sizeof *resultPtr`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Indeed, that would even be more DRY and thus better.

Comment: Yes that fixed the issue but i think am going to have to spend some time reviewing the code as the data is written from sonicThread to struct but is being read as 0 on SonicNav side.